# Include guest email in google calender export with java script

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the line from the code I downloaded. I would like to replace `getLocation` with the attendee's email address in order to export calendar events to a Google sheet.

```
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
```

I have tried the following variations based on what I have found in Google's Apps Script references:

```
getEmail()
getEmail(email)
getAttendee()
getGuestbyEmail()
getGuestbyEmail(email)
```

When using any of these I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getEmail in object CalendarEvent. (line 59, file "Code")
```

Any suggestions how to include the attendee's name? Each meeting represents an appointment for one client, so there will never be more than one, but if there is, the others should be ignored. This is the java script I am using:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1reNHZwbt4YXu-LdUcoLpv6QR4jnw9TqDH_Evmdn1D1c/copy

Answer (score 0):

[getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getEmail()) will only return the email address if [it's available](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) as per the official calendar API = "The attendee's email address, if available. This field must be present when adding an attendee"

To get the guest's name, use [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getname):

> Gets the name of the guest. If the name of the guest is not available,
>   this method returns the guest's email address.

Comment: When I try any of these, the code won't run ... I get an error such as: `TypeError: Cannot find function getEmail in object CalendarEvent. (line 59, file "Code")` Yet I know that there are invites with email addresses within the events. getName renders the same sort of error result.